# Eclipse maven parent child dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm attempting to develop this project in Eclipse and am having an issue with Maven within Eclipse.

github.com jbruinink/ng2boot

The steps I'm following are as follow:

1. In eclipse create new Spring Starter Project with Web dependency
2. copy the contents of the ng2boot git repo to the new project
3. run maven clean in eclipse
4. run maven install in eclipse.
5. Setup and run new Maven run configuration with spring-boot:run as the goal

Whala, it works. However, either my classpath is screwed up or my project is not referencing the maven dependencies as my java classes lose their reference to the spring boot dependencies.

***Before*** I copy the source from ng2boot a Maven Dependencies folder exists (see below):

[image: BEFORE]

***After*** I copy the source, it disappears and now my Java project `src` can't find the spring boot dependencies (see below):

[image: AFTER]

I don't understand why the child POM under the backend folder doesn't create the required maven dependencies folder.

I've also tried running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` which does absolutely nothing. I've spent hours on this an cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the need of the `backend` folder in your project? In Eclipse it should only show `src/main/java`etc. as source folder...

Comment: Why am I limited to src/main/java as the src folder? I understand what you're saying, my setup is non-conforming, regardless I should still be able to configure maven/eclipse to accommodate. I rather prefer the backend/frontend setup as it delineates between the logical purpose of each module. I'm not opposed to moving the backend folder "up a directory" to resolve this issue. I am however interested in understanding why this doesn't work.